# How do unit test the rules of vuetify v-text field with jest?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

For an vuetify v-text field which is having rules element for validation purpose. May I know how to do unit testing for those rules part using Jest unit test.

Comment: code snippet:
data: nameRules: [v => !!v || 'Name is required'],
<v-text-field
        v-model="contactReport.firstName"
        label="First Name"
        type="text"
        :rules="nameRules"
        required
        name="FirstName"
      ></v-text-field>

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the validation method from your tests and then verify that the output is expected.

In your case, you'll mount the component you're testing, then call `wrapper.vm.nameRules('value to test')`. Save what returned from that function in a variable, then validate that the response is what you expected with an `expect` statement: `expect(response).toEqual(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Been fighting with this a little bit; here is one solution, albeit somewhat undesirable...

**Solution**: Targeting the component validation rules directly, and supplying values and asserting the outcome.

**Caveats**: I don't fully like this approach as it requires accessing the rules by index, but it does get the job done.

If you wanted to play with this locally, I've included the code blocks below for ease of copy paste.

#### `SomeComponent.vue`

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "SomeComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      myRules: [
        (value) => value > 5 || "It's less than 5, error",
        (value) => value < 100 || "It's more than 100, error",
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

---

#### `sometest.spec.js`

```
import SomeComponent from "@/components/SomeComponent.vue"

describe("Sample tests", () => {
    it('should execute rules', () => {
        var rules = SomeComponent.data().myRules;
        expect(rules[0](-1)).toBe("It's less than 5, error")
        expect(rules[1](-1)).toBe(true)
    })
});
```

[image: Example unit test]